# Javascript variable showing up as undefined in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

At the top of my page, I grab a value of a hidden input field, store it as a variable, then try to use it in my Backbone code.  But, the value shows up undefined.  How can I get the value of the field first, and then initialize my backbone app?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var whitedealsToken = $('#usertoken').val();
    console.log(whitedealsToken)

    WhiteDeals.initialize();

});
</script>
```

**EDIT:  Full Backbone Code Below**

```
window.WhiteDeals = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  initialize: function() {
    new WhiteDeals.Routers.Deals();
    if (!Backbone.history.started) {
        Backbone.history.start();
        Backbone.history.started = true;
    }
  }
};

WhiteDeals.Routers.Deals = Backbone.Router.extend({

 routes: {
            "":   "index"
     },

     index: function() {
       var deals = new WhiteDeals.Collections.Deals();
       var dealsview = new WhiteDeals.Views.DealsIndex({
        el: $('#container')
       });
     }

});

WhiteDeals.Collections.Deals = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: WhiteDeals.Models.Deal,
  url: 'http://lvh.me:3000/api/v1/special_deals?access_token=' + whitedealsToken,
  parse: function(response) {
  return response.results;
  },
  // Overwrite the sync method to pass over the Same Origin Policy
  sync: function(method, model, options) {
     var that = this;
     var params = _.extend({
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         url: that.url,
         processData: false
     }, options);

    return $.ajax(params);
  }

 }); // End Collection
```

Comment: Is it undefined when you log it, or when you try to use it for the `url` in the collection?

Comment: It is defined when it is logged, and undefined when using it for the url.

Comment: Are you extending your models and collections in the initialize function? Variables passed as parameters in `.extend()` will only contain their value at the time `.extend()` is called, so unless you're extending them after `whitedealsToken` has been set (which you shouldn't be) they won't reference it properly.

Comment: metadept, the full code has been pasted above.  You can see everything being initialized properly (I think).  But, after reading your comment, I'm still not sure where I define that variable to get it to stay defined when I need to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing `whitedealsToken` in your extend call which is executing essentially as soon as the script runs. Since `whitedealsToken` isn't actually being assigned a value until $(document).ready, it's going to be undefined where you're trying to use it. You would need to put your .extend call *inside* the same $(document).ready block *after* you've assigned a value to the variable in question.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable in a function, it is only available in the local scope.  So outside of that function it does not exist.

Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx

You could instead make it global:

```
whitedealsToken = $('#usertoken').val();  // no var keyword
```

Or make it a property of some other global object:

```
WhiteDeals.whitedealsToken = $('#usertoken').val();
```

Or pass it into your `initialize` method and do something like this:

```
var whitedealsToken = $('#usertoken').val();
console.log(whitedealsToken)

WhiteDeals.initialize(whitedealsToken);
```

This last one by itself would not fix it, you would have to do some more work to pass the token into the instantiated collection at some point.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I can't get any of these to work.  I've pasted my full code above.